# QFN Programming / Tester / Adapter

Tags: integrated-circuit, soldering, programmer, qfn

I need to be able to test a batch of components ordered abroad. Soldering and removing them one by one would take a long time.

[image: QFN]

I need to be able to read this 6 by 4 component. But can't find anything online that can do the job. Can anyone lead me in the right direction? Or is my only route really to create a custom pcb and solder and desolder each one?

Comment: @NickAlexeev I would ideally like to create multiple chip testers for our company. Most chips are coming from Alibaba and cost between £5-10 and we would like to be able to test in a few seconds, gets the job done fast. Most are going to be sold to our customers and we don't want to risk sending out any defective components at all. Maybe using something like pogo pins in a rectangle arrangement? If I could get a valid path to execute this idea, I'm sure it's doable but just need to visualise it.

Comment: you could perhaps contract a watchmaker to make a custom socket.

Comment: Thanks @Jasen for the suggestion

Comment: @mathematics did you check octopart? https://octopart.com/search?autosugg_idx=4&currency=USD&oq=Pi3usb&q=pi3usb30532zlex&specs=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a QFN ZIF (zero insertion force) socket.
(A few manufacturers include [Aprilog](https://www.aprilog.com/ZIF_QFNpads.html) and [Test sockets](https://www.test-socket.com/#40), but they only have square pined QFN ZIF sockets listed). It's likely that manufactures mostly produce square QFN sockets because square packages are much more common. You might reach out and see if there are custom modules avalible.

It's also likely that you wouldn't have to test every single component, and just spot test the reel\tray\tube that the components come in, or every X components (depending on how much time and resources you have). I'd probably check at least 3 or 4 in the same package. You also might want to consider the cost of rework and ask the assembly house how much rework is (and get a quote), because if you could test the part natively on the PCB you are installing these on, it might not be that much more costly to do rework then testing them in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for that @Voltage Spike. Yes, I am seeing trouble finding a rectangle. What I may just do is test small amounts of those rectangle components and buy one of these square sockets for other chips. Appreciate the help and the link. Sorry I can't upvote you, no rep.